# Extract text from a DIV that occurs on multiple pages on a website, then output to .txt?

Tags: php, html, web, web-crawler

Just to note from the start, the content is uncopyrighted and I would like to automate the process of acquiring the text for the purpose of a project.

I'd like to extract the text from a particular and recurring DIV (*that is attributed with it's own 'class', in case that makes it easier*) sitting in each page on a simply designed website.

There is a single archive page on the site with a list of all of the pages containing the content I would like.

The site is www.zenhabits.net

I imagine this could be achieved with some sort of script, but have no idea where to start.

I appreciate any help.

-Nathan.

Comment: so shall i jut write it for you? and where do i send the bill? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.

Firstly, get all the links from this site, and throw them all into an array:

```
set_time_limit(0);//this could take a while...

ignore_user_abort(true);//in case browser times out


$html_output=file_get_contents("http://zenhabits.net/archives/");

# -- Do a preg_match on the html, and grab all links:
if(preg_match_all('/<a href=\"http:\/\/zenhabits.net\/(.*)\">/',$html_output,$matches)) {
# -- Append Data To Array
foreach($matches[1] as $secLink) {  
    $links[] = "http://zenhabits.net/".$secLink;
}
    }
```

I tested this for you, and:

```
//first 3 are returning something weird, but you don't need them - so I shall remove them xD
unset($links[0]);
unset($links[1]);
unset($links[2]);
```

No that's all done, time to go through all of THOSE links (in the array $links), and take its content:

```
foreach($links as $contLink){

$html_output_c=file_get_contents("$contLink");


    if(preg_match('|<div class=\"post\">(.*)</div>|s',$html_output_c,$c_matches)) {
    # -- Append Data To Array   
echo"data found <br>";
    $contentFromPage[] = $c_matches[1];
    }
else{echo "no content found in: $contLink -- <br><br><br>";}
}//end of foreach
```

I've basically just written a whole crawler script for you..

And now, loop the content array, and do whatever you want with it(here we shall put it into a text file):

```
//$contentFromPage now contains all of div class="post" content (in an array) - so do what you want with it

    foreach($contentFromPage as $content){

    # -- We need a name for each text file --
$textName=rand()."_content_".rand().".txt";//we'll just use some numbers and text

//define file path (where you want the txt file to be saved)
$path="../";//we'll just put it in a folder above the script
$full_path=$path.$textName; 

// now save the file..

file_put_contents($full_path,$content);

//and that's it

    }//end of foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the SimpleHTML DOM Parser script to extract the content. This is a very useful script that I had used for 1.6 year. You can download the script from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . It is well documented with examples. Hope this will help you to solve your problem.