# Extract text from multiple div of same name

Tags: php, html, extract, scrape

What I'm trying to do is extract text from a (non-copyright) site. I only need the text from inside a specific div. Let's say the div is called 'foo'. There are about 20 "foo divs" on each page and I would like to extract the text from each of these and output onto the page or externally to text, it doesn't matter.

Doing multiple pages at once would definitely be a bonus.

I've read the question on this site [Extract text from a DIV that occurs on multiple pages on a website, then output to .txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295669/extract-text-from-a-div-that-occurs-on-multiple-pages-on-a-website-then-output)

It seems similar to what I'm asking, if not identical. Not sure if this one will extract from multiple divs of the same name within one page however.

I tried copying and pasting all the code into a new .php file and it didn't work. I got error messages on running :(

I did do html for a few years when I was younger, but my php skills are very basic.

Also, I don't need the script to crawl or anything, just scrape the info. If there is an option for multiple URLs I'd like to input them manually.

Thanks

Comment: You should post the error messages that you got.

Comment: maybe the websites you want to retrieve info from have RSS/REST services ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `foo div`? If you mean that the `name` attribute value of the div is `foo` you can use [SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to easily retrieve this with a query like.

`$ret = $html->find('div[name=foo]');`

You then could iterate through these results storing them wherever you feel appropriate.  If you are running the script manually it would probably be a good idea to write these results right to a file?

The simple dom parser link above gives you step by step on how to scrape a website.

For us to help you, it's best if you post your code, and exact errors the more information you give the better answers you can receive.  If you're hoping that SO writes the script for you that parses webpages you will probably be dissappointed.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links might be of some help to you about HTML DOM PARSING in PHP

[Quick Start](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart)
[How to create HTML DOM object?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_create)
[How to find HTML elements?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)
[How to access the HTML element's attributes?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access)
[How to traverse the DOM tree?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse)
[How to dump contents of DOM object?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_dump)
[How to customize the parsing behavior?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_callback)
[API Reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)
[FAQ](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm)

ALso here's an  example for Scraping from a sample site *( www.slashdot.org )*

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://slashdot.org/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```